# Dealing with class method name conflicts in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, apollo, es6-class, lit-html

## tl;dr:

My class' method name conflicts with the same name on the class it extends from. I could just rename my class, but I'd prefer a solution which doesn't require a breaking change.

## Background

I publish a library called [`lit-apollo`](http://github.com/bennypowers/lit-apollo), which exports a `class` that extends from [`LitElement`](http://github.com/Polymer/lit-element). Users are meant to define their own `customElements` with my class, those elements then can use apollo graphql for data, and render using lit-html. See [README](http://github.com/bennypowers/lit-apollo) for a simple example.

## The Problem

LitElement's latest version exposes an instance method called `update`, which implementations can optionally override to control how and when the element renders. *My* library also has an `update` property, which corresponds the the [`update` option of Apollo mutation constructors](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/apollo-client.html#ApolloClient.mutate).

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag'
import { ApolloMutation, html } from 'lit-apollo/apollo-mutation'

const mutation = gql`
    mutation($id: ID!) {
      MyMutation(id: $id) {
        myResponse
      }
    }
`

const updateFunc = (cache, response) => 
  cache.writeData(doSomethingWith(cache, response))

class MutatingElement extends ApolloMutation {
  constructor() {
      this.mutation = mutation;
      this.variables = {id: "foo"};
      // here's where we break the LitElement contract
      this.update = updateFunc;
  }

  render() {
    return html`<div>${this.data.myResponse}</div>`
  }
}

customElements.define('mutating-element', MutatingElement)
```

These two methods, clearly are conflicting.

## The Question

I know I could just issue a breaking change to `lit-apollo` which renames it's own `update` method to `onUpdate` or some similar, but how might I address this problem without breaking my classes' APIs and thus requiring a major version?

I've though of checking the first argument to see if it's an instance of ApolloCache, then routing the args to `super.update` as needed, but I think that would break the LitElement contract, preventing users from implementing their own version of LitElement's `update`

How would you deal with this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know I could just issue a breaking change to `lit-apollo`, but how might I address this problem without breaking my classes' APIs?

You cannot, really. But it's not your fault:

> `LitElement`'s latest version exposes an instance method called `update`

*That* was the breaking change. So if you update your `lit-element` dependency to the latest version, you have to make a major version as well. Renaming your `update` method for that is natural. Alternatively, keep your API and continue using the old `lit-element` version.

Comment: Sounds about right. A possible strategy for updating in the future is to make a new version that deprecates `update` and say it's going to be removed/renamed/whatever in the next major version and present an alternative. This will give users some time to update.

Comment: FWIW: Both LitElement and lit-apollo were in the 0.x series, which has much more lenient semver rules. Since the previous version had an 0.x-dev version, I opted to simply issue a patch. Thanks to all for the advice.